# I keep getting "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error after typing g++ --version

Tags: g++, mingw

I have added C:\MinGW\bin to the system path, but I still get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's in `C:\MinGW\bin`?

Comment: Please show basic trouble shooting steps such as listing the directory contents, showing the exact `PATH` value, running the command from the directory.

Comment: A bunch of applications if you want to see the exact names here they are:                 edit - past character limit

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, but what to you mean by running command from the directory (I just started learning c)

Comment: `cd C:\MingGW\bin` then `g++`. Also, note that `g++` is for C++ not C code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm not interested in learning C++ at the moment, but do you know of any equivalent of g++ for C

Comment: It's `gcc`. Should be included in the same place as `g++`. But you need to get past these basic system problems first (which are nothing to do with the language or code).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the system path will not take effect on open programs, so to be safe you should reboot first.

But you don't need to add to the system path. For example in Command Prompt you can do this before running your build commands:

```
SET PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
```

Also note that plain MinGW is a bit outdated and you should consider moving to MinGW-w64, which exists for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.
A standalone build can be downloaded from https://winlibs.com/